# Java config.properties file won't save

Tags: java, properties

I have the following class that should allow to:

1. Send the caller the value of a property,
2. Set a new value for a property and save the Property file.

Sending the value of a property works.
Setting a new value for a property, and saving the file, that part don't work.

What is wrong?

I already searched a lot and many different ways are discussed everywhere, nothing that can help me.  That's why I have to ask here.

Many thanks to anybody who can help me!

```
public class Config {
private Properties props = new Properties();
private String strFilePath = "Config.properties";
private File configFile = new File(strFilePath);

public Config(){
    try {
        InputStream in = Config.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(strFilePath);
        props.load(in);

        }catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
}
public String getPropriete(String sPropriété){
    String strResult = "";
    try{
        strResult = props.getProperty(sPropriété);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
        strResult = "";
    }
    return strResult;
}
public void setPropriete(String sPropriété, String sValeur){
    try{
        System.out.println(sPropriété + " --> " + sValeur);
        props.setProperty(sPropriété, sValeur);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(strFilePath);
        props.store(fos, null);
        props.save(fos, null);
        Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8"));
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        fos.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: properties.save is deprecated, you can use store (which you are already using), try removing the line `props.save(fos, null);`

Comment: You don't need `props.save()` -- it is deprecated. You don't need `Writer out ...`, as it isn't doing anything.

Comment: Also, you are not providing a full path on the save. Whereas the `load` will find the file anywhere on the classpath, the `.store()` is going to save in the current directory. Have you verified that you are not getting another `Config.properties` file created somewhere?

Comment: @KevinO Yes I have found another file in /src.  I will try to add the specific path.  Also, I removed the part about the Writer-thing.  I'll get back asap

Comment: Thank you very much @KevinO, I had to change the path to "src/" + strFilePath for the FileOutpurStream, and i cleared the code to remove the Writer part.  Now, it works !  Many thanks, I really wish we could mark a comment as most useful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this:

```
   try{
        System.out.println(sPropriété + " --> " + sValeur);
        props.setProperty(sPropriété, sValeur);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(strFilePath);
        props.store(fos, null);
        fos.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```